# Iterate over different diagonals in a matrix and establishing its starting and end points in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, diagonal

I am trying to create a function that iterates over a diagonal in a chess-like game and returns a value if any of the positions are not empty.
The code below is for horizontal movements. I just have no idea how to translate this for diagonal movements.

I imagine that the increments for [r] and [c] must happen at the same time so that it moves diagonally. How can I do this?

```
int checkHorizontal(int fromr, int fromc, int toc){
    if (fromc < toc){
        for(int c = fromc + 1; c < toc; c++){
            if ((tablero[fromr][c]) != &empty){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (fromc > toc){
        for(int c = toc + 1; c < fromc; c++){
            if ((tablero[fromr][c]) != &empty){
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I expect the function to return 0 if one of the spaces is not empty and 1 if all of them were empty.

Comment: A diagonal is cell is a[i][i].

Comment: That's right only for the main diagonal in a square matrix. The diagonal movements of the Bishop piece can be in any direction and are not necessarily in the main diagonal

Comment: Diagonal movement from a[r][c] is a[r+/-i][c+/-i]

Answer (score 0):

The **left diagonal** can be indexed as follow:

```
Matrix[i][i]
```

where **i** starts from **0** to **((matrix size)-1)** and incremented by one each loop

The **right diagonal** can be indexed as follow:

```
Matrix[j][i]
```

where **i** starts from **0** and incremented by one each loop and **j** starts from **(matrix-1)** and decremented by one each loop.

---

**Note** : This indexing is for square matrix only

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
for (int c = fromc + 1, r = fromr + 1; c < toc; c++, r++) {
    do_stuff_with(tablero[r][c])
}
```

to increment two variables together.

Of course you can also do `c++, r--` to move the coordinates in different directions.

Answer (score 0):

At a diagonal `x` and `y` either increment or decrement by 1.

So from a certain `[x, y]` point there are 4 different directions: `x++`/`y++`, `x++`/`y--`, `x--`/`y++`, or `x--`/`y--`.

Increment, in all above 4 directions, until you hit `0` or `N - 1` (`N` array size).